# 2D shape matching in c++

Tags: c++, pattern-matching, shapes

I have a set of sequential points which makes a 2D shape and i have another set which might be making the similar shape but this shape is different in scale and rotation from the last one. What are the best approaches/options to match and calculate the score of similarity of these two shapes .

Comment: If I understand you correctly, as you know scale factor and orientation (rotation) then make it the same for both shapes, and then compare points coordinates. Or use scale & orientation in your compare routine per point (so you "translate" point before comparison )

Comment: i don't know the scale and orientation , i suppose i could find it out somehow . but wouldn't that be reinventing the wheel ? i am looking for some per-existing solutions that i could refer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best thing i found after few days of research is [$1 gesture recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/), it is scale and rotation invariant and also has implementation in many languages including C++ .

Answer (score 3):

Compare the angles at the vertices of each shape. If they match one by one the shapes are similar. You might have to 'rotate' one of the shapes during the process. Remember similar triangles their angles match one by one.

Comment: One thing I missed is that you should also check the ratio of the 'matching' edges. It should be constant!

Comment: If the angles match the ratio is constant!